# What is better for android application development? Is it kotlin or java?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to android. I am confused what to learn android studio or kotlin. I don't know anything about android development.

Comment: @mokshfreelancer Kotlin is a language that runs in the JVM, like Java.  That's how it can be used to develop Android apps.  I did a quick search for `Android Kotlin tutorial` on YouTube and got a lot of results.  Try to use that as a starting point.

Comment: There are so many resources on internet that answers this question. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting any question.

Comment: You can learn from Udacity. https://in.udacity.com/courses/android. The courses are taught by Google Engineers.

Comment: Rumor has it that when someone learns Kotlin, they will not look back to write code in Java again (unless they have to)...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to learn either Java or Kotlin for Android application development. Android studio is an IDE like eclipse which helps you to develop applications. 
Kotlin is a Programming language like Java.
So if you are confused about learning Java or Kotlin to develop Android applications, your question makes sense. Here is a comparision:

Kotlin for Android : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/android-overview.html

**What Java has that Kotlin does not**

Checked exceptions, 
Primitive types that are not classes, 
Static members, 
Non-private fields, 
Wildcard-types

**What Kotlin has that Java does not**

Extension functions, 
Null-safety, 
Lambda expressions + Inline functions, 
structuresSmart casts, 
String templates, 
Properties, 
Primary constructors, 
First-class delegation, 
Type inference for variable and property types, 
Singletons, 
Declaration-site variance & Type projections, 
Range expressions, 
Operator overloading, 
Companion objects, 
Data classes, 
Separate interfaces for read-only and mutable collections, 
Coroutines

Source : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/comparison-to-java.html

Full Kotlin Ref : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-docs.pdf

Comment: The best answer I have got. You cleared my all doubts. Thank you very very much.

Comment: @mokshfreelancer Happy learning:)

Answer (score 2):

Java and Kotlin are programming languages. You're safe learning either one, but since Java is much older it will be easier to find books, tutorials, and sample code in Java than in Kotlin.

Android Studio is just the IDE, or text editor (+ sdk, emulator, etc....) you write your code on.

Learning one doesn't mean much for the other.

You could learn Java, and write your code on Android Studio, or Eclipse, or even Sublime text (and run the app from command prompt/terminal)